# Android MAP TO TABS

Tags: android, tabs, android-mapview, addition

Hey I have tried a lot of ways of creating tabs which went ok, although when I add a map to it it crashes, I tried what this guy did here: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=86

My application crashes before any tabs appear. The code is below:

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Tabs extends MapActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

```
private static final String HOME_TAG = "Home";
private static final String PLAYERS_TAG = "Players";
private static final String MAP_TAG = "Map";
private static final String TICKET_TAG = "Ticket";

private TabHost tabHost;
private MapView mapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(HOME_TAG).setIndicator("Home").setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(PLAYERS_TAG).setIndicator("Players").setContent(new Intent(this, Players.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAG).setIndicator("Venue").setContent(new TabContentFactory () {

        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return mapView;
        }
    }));

    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC33"));
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3399FF"));
}

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC33"));
        }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3399FF"));
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

And my manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/englandrugbyrose" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Tabs" />
    <activity android:name=".Home" />
    <activity android:name=".Players" />
    <activity android:name=".Tickets" />
    <activity android:name=".Map" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Btw, my XML are in different XML files such as map.xml that contains the mapview id for loading the content, thats the only difference between mine and that other guys XML.

UPDATE: logcat

It points to line 35 at the mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); With a nullpointer exception

Thanks.

Comment: a printout of the error from logcat will be more helpful than the code you pasted.  It should give a line number that caused the crash.

Comment: I'm not familiar with logcat? what is that?

Comment: I have got the logcat open, I am getting a nullpointer exception at like code 35. When I double click on it, it highlights the mapView.setBuiltInZoom(true);

Comment: take a look at the line that has the nullpointer exception and askyourself: What could be null here?  Why is it null?  Then fix it :-)  At that point if you don't understand why something is null It may be better to ask that in your question specifically. Also, is there a mapview with the id called mapview in your main.xml file??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downgrading to API level 7? I had that problem with the mapView.setBuiltInZoom(true) when I was on API level 8. The exception stopped when I changed to API level 7.